# byte/ bit usage and ASCII support for symbols

Tags: utf-8, byte, ascii, bit, symbols

- Where do I find the bit usage symbols out of the below. I understand that UTF8 is minmum Octate bits and UTF16 is minimum 2 Bytes.
- Are all of the symbols below ASCII supported?
- Which is the smallest (two smallest) memory usage symbols below:

Symbols:

```
~ ` @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + = - { } [ ] : ; " ' < > , . ? /
```

Comment: Those are all ASCII-supported values and encode in one byte in both [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  Note that ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 so a valid ASCII-encoded string is also valid UTF-8.

Comment: I saw 7 bit binary and 8 bit binary. Does that mean it will use a 7 bit binary will hold 7 bits of space or a 8 bit binary space. It does according to me but just checking.

Comment: Wikipedia describe the encoding of many symbols. Unicode site (the technical one) has the character database (and the standard to see how to encode): all of the public and free. But you can define your encoding with just the number of character you need (and so it has optimal number of bits: also fractional if needed): just treat the number of symbols as a numeric base of your new digit (so string) encoding. (for convenience add also "END-OF-STRING" character)

Comment: How many lowest bits will be a `.` or a `*` or a `@` or a `;` or a `:` or a `-` and in which encoding system? I am unable to get the lowest memory usage?

Comment: @Gary the smallest data type that a component can access is a byte. Every ASCII character fits inside a single byte, and use up at most 7 bits per byte. All of the characters you have shown are ASCII characters, so they are all byte-sized, and their high bit (possibly more) of each byte will always be 0. Refer to an ASCII Table to determine which bits each character uses. UTF-8, on the other hand, uses all 8 bits of each byte, where an ASCII character is encoded in 1 byte, and a non-ASCII character is encoded in 2-4 bytes, depending on the character's numeric value.

Comment: if i have to compare these symbols (  `;`, `.`, `@`, `*`, `:`, `-`, `;` ) and get minimum bits used in UTF-8 and n network buffer packets, what will it be for each.